# How to identify account type

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I get list of accounts by using `getAccount()` and `discoverAndAddAccounts()`. For each account type (CREDIT, LOAN, etc...), there are specific set of fields that I need to access. For example, I want to access creditMaxAmount field of CreditAccount. However, i dont seem to find a way to identify "type" of a given account object.

In summary, given output of above mentioned functions, how do I identify account type in order to access fields specific to that account type.

Comment: Could you provide more info please? What SDK are you using? Is this for QuicKBooks online or QuickBooks for windows?

Comment: I am using AggCat apis

Answer (score 3):

The type of account is identified by the Account header.

See https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/index.php?title=0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0020_Aggregation_%26_Categorization_Apps/AggCat_API/0020_API_Documentation/0050getLoginAccounts for the response XML.

As you can see there is InvestmentAccount, CreditAccount, BankingAccount, LoanAccount, ..., and OtherAccount.

If an account shows up as OtherAccount, that means that it has not been set to a specific account. You can use updateAccountType to set the type of account it should be.

Comment: -> I understand that account type is part of xml response, but i am not sure how to access it in java. Account type does not seem to have any field that holds account type. For example when I get accountList by using getLoginAccounts or getAccount and access an account from account list in the following way, I do not see any field that holds account type accountList.getBankingAccountsAndCreditAccountsAndLoanAccounts().get(0)

Answer (score 2):

```
<ns8:AccountList xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/account/v1" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/creditaccount/v1" 
    xmlns:ns3="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/rewardsaccount/v1" 
    xmlns:ns4="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/bankingaccount/v1" 
    xmlns:ns5="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/investmentaccount/v1" 
    xmlns:ns6="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/otheraccount/v1" 
    xmlns:ns7="http://schema.intuit.com/aggregation/loanaccount/v1" 
    xmlns:ns8="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/accountlist/v1">
   <ns7:**LoanAccount**>
      <accountId>75000033014</accountId>
      <accountNumber>9900009994</accountNumber>
      <accountNickname>My Military Loan</accountNickname>
      <displayPosition>5</displayPosition>
      <institutionId>0</institutionId>
      <description>Description</description>
      <balanceAmount>90227.2</balanceAmount>
      <aggrSuccessDate>2012-02-27T23:20:13.651-08:00</aggrSuccessDate>
      <aggrAttemptDate>2012-02-27T23:20:13.651-08:00</aggrAttemptDate>
      <aggrStatusCode>0</aggrStatusCode>
      <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
      <ns7:loanType>**MILITARY**</ns7:loanType>
```

Comment: How do I fetch account type using AggCat apis in java code ? I tried but could not find any field that represents account type

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to identify the Account type, the getBankingAccountsAndCreditAccountsAndLoanAccounts() method will return the Accounts, and you would need to check the Object type in order to determine the Account type.